# How to solve this text?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request

When I try to pull content of **amazon.com**, Node.js request module gives text to console like this:

```
?y?H>5Z??{???O???↔??????|◄???♦?<∟?h??j??B??43?!>ã?l???∟???        ??M??v6?
eP$r|???$;??☼?Thc???ea??l?p??k?▼??☺↓i???L?v7?x?6??M#tA??↕v?Z)?p1´?vQ??9?ET?1???J
?_c?☼↨u?Î%5↨??q??¶▬l??→1↨?$??h?_??J-;??r???+?▲?F?Hw?♦????lE?Qs?Hx??o9@??V3??
L?bk?fcb??????o?E9??]????"??}x♦7?7r→?z0KE??Z?▬?4?I?A??R↨???/s<???☻V`?f!????3?2;?
?????L???????!?OA9↕iC?/????r?0??U?♫M?♂?}y???=,e?M?↔Q[¶`xn?|B??w?D♫f?↓?↨☻n¶????
zH??4p??☻???O?☻♠????w↨?????P'???z?etXN'?U??`??Z??♀">♀j????????????5???!?????#u??
0X?i?zb?☺?[?&∟?>??‼??Q??+???}???z▲A???9§????O????♠????  ?∟?es???j??D0J?s?[?;U??!
???l0???u       i35_???∟x???2<RF???{???\d♥<?8?W?p>◄→]?????¶+???|(???☻z??♦??v??8⌂
,?"▲??∟?l???1?A?7zt??Q,?'??♥?n???♦,??r?N?H\?-?YA>)?♦??|X?C;I?q⌂]r↓?H??¶D??????>C
?X??? ?b???o?_+R?9??8??^??_???‼????_*v?↓?♣  ??"♠?♀!J1?Ib????u??Bg?a?S??↕?d1??&hZ
?H?↑?N♣???!?⌂|b?.0?&'▬?→?C*5ukp?▲4?☻>?7♣??,????2?\??$?X??4?T7???H7?$5?"?????,I?→
h??zy↕?▼???☻7??J]Ab1|rF?&^?↔??J]SG??<??►4?☺?↕?♥B?~P? 9∟?e|.BR?0♥?           ???]
```

Whereas, when I try to pull data from **amazon.co.uk**, as we expected, it gives html structured output like that:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>
```

How can I solve first scenario? How can I get html content? Are there any way to do this?

Code:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0085EY4MS';
const fs = require('fs');

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){

    fs.writeFile('mynewfile3.txt', html, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!');
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err){

  });
```

Comment: Could you possibly add the code you used so that we can see how you obtained the first scenario, please?

Comment: @ChanceShaffer edited

Comment: I replicated your issue @Murat Ç.. Let me take a look at a thing or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turns the issue is with the encoding of the request. You can add an option for the type of encoding and this will resolve your issue. The updated code is below:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs');

const opts = {
    uri: "http://www.amazon.com/Fallout-76-PlayStation-4/dp/B07DD9571S",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    },
    gzip: true, //Added to fix the issue
}

rp(opts)
  .then(function(html){

    fs.writeFile('mynewfile3.txt', html, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!');
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The header is not required.